# socket.io emit callback not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
function MainController () {
 var self = this;

self.mainInfo = null;

self.socket = io.connect('http:/192.168.56.101:3000');

self.login = function () {
self.socket.emit("login", "Hello");
}


self.socket.on('welcome', function () {
console.log('welcome');
});

self.socket.on('player leave', function () {
console.log('leave');
});


self.login();
};
```

Above is front-end code. I can receive emit messages, google chrome logs incoming message

```
5:::{"name":"welcome"}
```

But console.log('welcome'); doesn't work. callback's don't fire

Answer (score 0):

A typo :(

```
 self.socket = io.connect('http://192.168.56.101:3000');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put self.login() inside 'connect' event handler because at the time login() got called, it's not guaranteed that the connection is established.

```
self.socket = io.connect('http://192.168.56.101:3000');

    :
    :

self.socket.on('connect', function() {
    self.login();
}
```